# JavaScript RegExp including flags in pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var str = 'TEST, STRING';
var regex = new RegExp('^(.*)('+str+')(.*)$/i');
console.log(regex);
```

Output

```
/^(.*)(TEST, STRING)(.*)$\/i/
```

But I need the following output:

```
/^(.*)(TEST, STRING)(.*)$\/i
```

Comment: If your problem is solved, please accept the answer. See [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 4):

The flags should be the second parameter to the [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) constructor.

```
new RegExp('^(.*)(' + str + ')(.*)$', 'i');
                                    ^ ^^^
```

The syntax of [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Syntax) constructor is

> `new RegExp(pattern[, flags])`

Comment: Use `  RegExp('^(.*)('+str+')(.*)$\//i');  `

Comment: @ArifBurhan And that'll give `/^(.*)(TEST, STRING)(.*)$\/\/i/`

Comment: Only `  \\  ` can output `  \  `

Comment: @ArifBurhan You're not getting it. The first param to the `RegExp` constructor is the `pattern`. To add _flags_, use second param.